# How to levarage spring batch without using POJO?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I know `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` class depends on POJO. 
But here is the thing: If I want to take advantage of Spring Batch features but do not want to create separate jobs ( does not want to write POJOs and separate reader writes or mappers) how to do this?

My requirement is to read *.csv file which will have the headers so I should be able to supply header names in a map or string[] and create my sql statement based on it, instead of writing a `RowMapper`.
This will help me uploading various files to different tables.
Is it possible to change `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`  to make it suitable to map the values from Map or String[]?

Also Even if I do not have headers in the *.cvs file, I can construct update statement and load using chunk delimeters setting and other advantages of Spring Batch.

Comment: Have you actually read the manual and javadocs of the various elements? I even believe there is a sample showing what you want.

Comment: Could you share the link if any? Tried finding it for last 3 days could not get it... May be approach is wrong

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please point out where exactly is this mentioned? I am reading everywhere that Spring Batch is completely depending on bean and it retrospects the bean.

Comment: Can someone let me know if it is possible to create a batch job without POJO. I have not found anything. In fact I have seen communication between authors of above classes that it is not possible.

Comment: As mentioned the samples of spring batch and the reference guide. Read the different interfaces and the implementations. You want one of the `FieldSetMapper` that either returns an `String[]` or just a plain `FieldSet`. And use a `DefaultLineMapper`. The `FieldSet` contains everything you need (column names, indexes etc.) you might need to implement a custom `ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider` which creates the proper mapping for named params of a `ItemProcessor` to construct a `Map` of the `FieldSet`. There are plenty of options and instead of guessing I again urge you to read the documentation.

Comment: Yes. I am able to get read any kind of file now. Just want to know if there is any interface to construct dynamic update statement with (?,?,?) depending on number of parameters in ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider? Thank for your input that confirm me that read like this was possible.